# Rake test failed - RunTimeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, error-handling, rake

I ran `rake test` and got the following error:

```
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:1213:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Permission denied (PG::Error)
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
.
.
. (many filenames)
.
.
Errors running test:units! #<PG::Error: could not connect to server: Permission denied
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
>
Errors running test:functionals! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/...]>
```

What does it mean? and what should I do to solve the issue?
also, it seems to relate to PostgresSql, but I don't use that database I believe. (Where can this be checked?) and so it doesn't make sense...

Update: I was wrong, there is postgresql. 
Here's my `config/database.yml` file:

```
test:
   adapter: postgresql
   encoding: unicode
   database: db_test
   pool: 5
   username: db
   password: 

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: db_production
  host: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  pool: 5
  username: xxxxx
  password: xxxxxxx
```

Here's the data from my Gemfile:

```
#Running a Postgres Database
gem 'pg'

#And using redis for KVS
gem 'redis'

#Behind a Thin Server
gem 'thin'
```

I am now working on my local machine, and this is a project I pulled. Perhaps my local machine has a certain databases (I'm using mysql I believe) but the application is expecting another?

Update:
My local machine (Mac os) does have postgresql, I was able to find it using `which psql`. How do I configure the database and make it all work without errors?

Comment: Informations on your config/database.yml can be important, you should post it. Delete the passwords in it before !

Comment: which database have you specified in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Thanks @ForgetTheNorm and @ Alex Lynham, I just posted the additional info

Answer (score 3):

if you don't have psql in local machine. just continue with mysql itself.

In your gemfile remove **gem 'pg'** and give **gem 'mysql2'**

give 
bundle install
rake db:create
rake db:migrate

before that give your mysql database password in database.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to several problems :

- The dabatase `db_test` doesn't exist
- The user `db` doesn't exist
- The user `db` have a password
- The `host` must be specified

In other words, take time to configure your `database.yml`, in the `test` part, and run a `rake db:test:prepare` to initialize your database.

All DB availables commands from rake : `rake -T | grep db`